Can you borrow library books on Chol Ha'moed?
Is it allowed to borrow books from the public library on Chol Ha'moed?  If so, why?
Please assume:

The books are about secular topics (e.g. health) which you enjoy reading about.
You plan to read the books on Chol Ha'moed.

If you borrow books, the loan information will be saved in the library's computer system.  Saving information in a computer may not always be allowed on Chol Ha'moed.
Edit
Is there anything I can do to improve this question?
Related

Library use on Chol Ha'moed: assisted checkout vs. self-checkout.
Returning library books on Chol Hamoed.


Could they have been rented before and you delayed till then for convenience? Or assume it's a new desire/opportunity

@DoubleAA:  Please consider both cases.  ❧  Should we split this question into two halves:  one for each case?

Typing on a computer is ksiva sheino shel kayama. Creating a situation where a non Jew does this for their own benefit shouldn't be assur.
